# setWindowSize не работает в браузере Chrome

Tags: javascript, dom, selenium-webdriver, test-automation

Я пишу тесты на CoffeeScript с использованием Webdriver.io и mocha. Код обрабатывается с помощью компилятора CoffeeScript.

По какой-то причине я не могу изменить размер окна браузера в Chrome. Согласно документации это можно сделать следующей функцией ([вот ссылка на описание функции](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/setWindowSize/)):

```
browser.setWindowSize(width, height)
```

В Mozilla Firefox размер окна с помощью данной функции устанавливается. Однако в Chrome размер остается прежним, при этом никаких ошибок нет.

Также я пробовал изменить размер окна, прописав его в DOM (при работе с webdriver объект window недоступен, поэтому приходится использовать browser.executeScript):

```
browser.executeScript('window.document.body.style.cssText = "width: 1920px";', []);
browser.executeScript('window.document.body.style.cssText = "heigth: 1080px";', []);
```

Результата также нет, размер окна браузера не меняется.

Как изменить размер окна браузера в Chrome?

Comment: А вы окно ресайзите которое создано через `window.open()`? Ресайзать окно можно только если вы создали через `window.open()`. Не знаю как с CoffeScript попробуйте нативный js метод [window.resizeTo()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resizeTo)

Comment: Я создаю новое окно через browser.newWindow('./url/path') (https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/newWindow/). Думаю, что это равносильные способы, тем более, что в мозиле ресайзить окно у меня получалось.

Comment: Проверил такой код в хроме: `window.open("https://google.com",
"mywindow","menubar=1,resizable=1,width=350,height=250");` и созданом окне пробовал задать `window.resizeTo(1000, 1000)` все работает. Я не сильно понимаю как вы создаете и потом размер меняете.

Comment: Проверил ваш код, вы полностью правы. Теперь осталось понять, как с помощью Webdriver.io найти новое окно, созданное с помощью window.open()

Comment: Тут: https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/newWindow/ пишут про функцию newWindow, что This command is the equivalent function to window.open(). Так что всё по-прежнему непонятно.

Comment: А что с этим окноп потом нужно делать? если нативным js то найти окно можно через переменную `let a = window.open( "",  "mywindow", "menubar=1,resizable=1,width=1000,height=1000" ); a.document.write("<h1>Hello word</h1>")` [документация](https://learn.javascript.ru/popup-windows). Я с Webdriver.io не знаком, не понимаю что вы хотите им реализовать

Comment: Переустановил Webdriver.io, всё заработало. Спасибо! Похоже, что дело было в неправильных настройках. С правильными настройками browser.setWindowSize(1920,1080) работает корректно.